# Highlight duplicates with only 2 colors

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, ms-office, color-codes

Each set of duplicates either shows with light yellow or dark

```
Sub ColorCompanyDuplicates()
'Updateby Extendoffice
Dim xRg, xRgRow As Range
Dim xTxt, xStr As String
Dim xCell, xCellPre As Range
Dim xCIndex As Long
Dim xCol As Collection
Dim I As Long
If ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Count > 1 Then
xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal
Else
xTxt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AddressLocal
End If
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("please select the data range:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
xCIndex = 2
Set xCol = New Collection
For I = 1 To xRg.Rows.Count
On Error Resume Next
Set xRgRow = xRg.Rows(I)
For Each xCell In xRgRow.Columns
xStr = xStr & xCell.Text
Next
xCol.Add xRgRow, xStr
If Err.Number = 457 Then
xCIndex = xCIndex + 1
Set xCellPre = xCol(xStr)
If xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex = xCIndex
xRgRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex
ElseIf Err.Number = 9 Then
MsgBox "Too many duplicate companies!", vbCritical, "Kutools for Excel"
Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0
xStr = ""
Next
End Sub
```

I want the above code limit to two colors only, light yellow and dark yellow in order to tell apart duplicates or the set of duplicates.

I tried limiting the above VBA code limit to only two colors to tell apart the duplicated values but I'm confused how to limit it to only two colors.

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything. You have butchered it quite well. Why don't you explain in detail what it is supposed to do?  Also, add a screenshot of your data and a link to the original on which this code is based i.e. we can recognize that it is the remains of an `Extendoffice` code.

Comment: Ahh @VBasic2008 give the new guy a break  - I ran the code and thought it worked beautifully - (you needed to enter a column of numbers or something like dog eat cat eat bread grow dog - then select it per the application.input box pop-up.  However-  I do agree withy you that the question could be made a little clearer but only ont the point of ""which duplicates do you want to make light and which dark?"*  "to tell apart duplicates or sets of duplicates" - so light if only 1 pair of identical cells; but anything more than that everything must go dark (because then we'd have 'sets'?see below

Answer (score 0):

Screesnhot/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9htEym-5d9EFJFuh1VA?e=JwGwnx) etc. refer:

**Code:**

*(fyi - minor amendments required for your code - essentially just manipulated the line that was changing colour each time a new pair of dups were identified - i.e. `xCIndex = 2`*

```
Sub ColorCompanyDuplicates2()
'best practice to define all variables / but cbb tbh 
k = 0
If ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Count > 1 Then
    xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal
Else
    xTxt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.AddressLocal
End If
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("please select the data range:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
If xRg Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If
xCIndex = 27
Set xCol = New Collection
For I = 1 To xRg.Rows.Count
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRgRow = xRg.Rows(I)
    For Each xCell In xRgRow.Columns
    xStr = xStr & xCell.Text
    Next
    xCol.Add xRgRow, xStr
    If Err.Number = 457 Then
        If Range("b2").Value = "Y" Then
            If xCIndex = 19 Then
                xCIndex = 27
            Else: xCIndex = 19
            End If
        Else
            k = k + 1
            If k = 1 Then
                go_back1 = xCellPre
            ElseIf k = 2 Then
                go_back2 = xCellPre
            Else
                xCIndex = 27
                go_back1.Interior.ColorIndex = xCIndex
                go_back2.Interior.ColorIndex = xCIndex
            End If
        End If
'xCIndex = xCIndex + 1
    
    Set xCellPre = xCol(xStr)
    If xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex = xCIndex
    xRgRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xCellPre.Interior.ColorIndex
    ElseIf Err.Number = 9 Then
    MsgBox "Too many duplicate companies!", vbCritical, "Kutools for Excel"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    xStr = ""
    Next
End Sub
```

---

**Deploy**

Was not quite sure as to how exactly the 'dark' and 'light'
shading was intended to operate (per my comment beneath your Q) - cell B2 has a drop-down validaiton list:

- *"Y": i.e. alternate between light/dark shades*
- *"N": only have light shaded yellow if there are no more than* *one pair of duplicate values, thereafter change **all** (including those otherwise shaded light) to dark yellow**

(amend code as req. if you intended/meant something completely different; note: when changing list opion in cell B2, and re-running code - you may need to first [manually] clear/remove the fomatting from the preceeeding run - such could easily be incorporated into logic/code as req.)

---

- *Have not tested columns/matrices - but code appears to be able to handle this as well*
- *some commentary pertained to something relating to kutools - am sure that if you took the time to copy/paste  / provide data in first ainstance - no issues would have identified (besides what the OP requires/is asking about)*
- *Commentary was particularly constructive to say least - that aside*
- *here's what it looks like in action!:*

[image: Animated GIF]

---

**But wait! there's more!**

This may /not serve your cause, but I created a radar chart represting how often various values (in this case, 1,2,3 , col D 'Data' crop up....

*Frequency table:*

=LET(x_,UNIQUE(SORT(D5:D51)),HSTACK(x_,COUNTIFS(D5:D51,x_)))

[image: Frequency function - hstack]

*requires Office 365 compatibile version of Excel.*

[image: Radar plot]

AS you can see, initial numbers (1,2,3) start increasing in freq - there is a step up at some point RE: DB- with numer (so th arange line becomese mnore volatile - but arger.

---